# uncaught exception: Syntax error, just updated jquery

Tags: jquery

Hey guys I am getting the following error...

> uncaught exception: Syntax error,
>   unrecognized expression:
>   [chunk_id=162494ddad5751534b1.85292984]

I just upgraded to jquery 1.5.1 and ui 1.8.13 so I was just wondering if anyone could catch what the error with this. The part where chunk_id is present is when div[chunk_id='+response.reply_chunk_id+'] is used. Is there something wrong with the way that is written? It breaks where I stopped the code so I figured the error must be there...

```
function success(response, status)  { 

          if(status == 'success') {
              if(response.reply_message=='1'){
                $('div[chunk_id='+response.reply_chunk_id+']').prepend(prepare(response));

        ......
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put quotes around the value in the selector.